# What percentage of window AC depth is outside?

Tags: air-conditioning

My HOA has a restriction of 16 inches depth on outside for a window A/C so wanted to know if a total depth of 21 inches for an AC is going to be fine.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the wall thickness, and where in that thickness is the window frame.

Comment: Typical window unit manuals are available online and will show a clearance diagram with measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it is going to vary from one model to another, but I have 4 window units in my basement right now and they are all about 80% outside, measured from the flange that rests against the inside of the window sash. (The amount that is "outside" will also depend on the thickness of the window.)

So I would say you're just about OK, depending on how exactly they measure.